# Is setting wrapper class a good practice?

Tags: java, android

I was thinking how to wrap all my settings and for example I use once or even more. Let's think a bit abstractive.

```
class WholeApplicationSettingsInHere{
    private static boolean setting1, setting2;

    WholeApplicationSettingsInHere(){set defaults}

    public static boolean getSetting1(){return setting1}
    public static void setSetting1(setting1){set setting1}

    public static boolean getSetting2(){return setting2}
    public static void setSetting2(setting2){set setting2}

    ...
}

class One(){
/*No fields in here, except private fields*/
    methodOne(){use variables from WholeApplicationSettingsInHere class}
    methodTwo(){}
}

class Two(){
/*No fields in here, except private fields*/
    methodOne(){use variables from WholeApplicationSettingsInHere class}
    methodTwo(){}
}
```

My question is if it will be a good practice to do things that way?

Comment: Yes if you are using getter to access and not changing the state of WholeApplicationSettingsInHere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty hard to answer "is this a good practice" because there isn't one definitive answer. It depends entirely on your context. You might want to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that more accurately reflects exactly what you're doing.

I will say that making those variables and methods static is a pretty horrible idea- what happens down the road if you want two instances of your settings class?

And before you say "I'll only ever need one instance of the settings"- you can't know that ahead of time. This is a misuse of the static keyword.

And at that point- why not just use an instance of the Properties class?

Comment: You understood exactly how I wanted. What you said about static is true. I didn`t think about it that way. I will now check the Properties class as You mentioned. Thank You for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

You should the `PreferenceManager` and `SharedPreferences` to store and retrieve user preferences. Using static booleans in a class doesn't really seem like a great idea.

Just create a simple class with your methods, for example:

```
public class PreferencesHelper {

    private PreferencesHelper() {} // No instantiation

    public static boolean getSetting1(Context context) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean(PREFERENCE_KEY, defaultValue);
    }

    public static void setSetting1(Context context, boolean value) {
       Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
       editor.putBoolean(PREFERENCE_KEY, value);
       editor.apply();
    }

}
```

And finally, to answer your question: Yes, it can be good practice, if you do something like the above-mentioned code. By doing so, you make it impossible to have preference keys scattered across your application, and it makes your code easier to read.

Having said that, if you're ever in a situation where you need to set multiple preferences at once, it's a bit of a waste having to call `setSetting1()`, `setSetting2()`, `setSetting3()`, etc., as you're recreating objects over and over again. In such cases, simply get the Edtior object, put all your changes, and apply the changes.

Comment: Okay. I changed my mind. You have right. It will be faster, need less time and resources. Thank you!

Comment: @Kris faster? SharedPreferences are relatively slow! If you Need the data beyond your activity lifecycle than you can take sharedpreferences. If you just Need the data inside activity LifeCycle, a static variable should be much faster..

Comment: @Mike Not using apply(). It makes the changes immediately in memory and kicks off a background task to update the database. Regardless, as long as you're only using the preferences a few times, you won't notice a difference. If you're using them often in the same class, you should cache them.